# Objective-C to Swift: correct way to translate a for-loop

Tags: objective-c, swift, for-loop, avcapturesession

I'm trying to convert this code to swift, but I keep getting an error in the if-statement, the objective-c code looks like this:

```
AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutPut;
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;

for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections){
      for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]){
          if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]){
          videoConnection = connection;
          break;
           }
      }
}
```

and my Swift code looks like this:

```
let stillImageOutPut = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

let videoConnection:AVCaptureConnection? = nil

        for connection in stillImageOutPut.connections{
            for port in [connection.inputPorts]{
                if
            }
        }
```

in the if-statement I can't find the `.mediaType` and the autocomplete says `description`, `getMirror` and `map`. I've tried casting the types in the for-loop in other ways but I just get keep getting errors.

Any suggestions on how to create this for-loop correctly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stillImageOutPut.connections` is an `NSArray` in Objective-C, and an `Array<AnyObject>` in Swift.  You'll want to cast it to `Array<AVCaptureConnection>` in Swift.  Similarly, you'll want to cast `connection.inputPorts` to `Array<AVCaptureInputPort>`.

```
let stillImageOutPut = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

var videoConnection:AVCaptureConnection? = nil

for connection in stillImageOutPut.connections as [AVCaptureConnection] {
    for port in connection.inputPorts as [AVCaptureInputPort] {
        if port.mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo {
            videoConnection = connection
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lose the brackets in `[connection.inputPorts]`. This is not Objective-C any longer! Those brackets, in Swift, mean an array, whereas in Objective-C they just signify message-sending. Simply change that line to:

```
for port in connection.inputPorts {
```

...and your world will brighten up considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this but I think it should work:

```
for connection in stillImageOutPut.connections{
    for port  in connection.inputPorts as [AVCaptureInputPort]{
        let mediaType = port.mediaType;
    }
}
```